# Interseção entre colunas pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Considerando dois dataframes como os que seguem abaixo:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[3,6,9,12,15]})
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'id': [2,4,6,8,10,12,14]})
```

Como contabilizar a interseção entre `df` e `df1`? Ou seja, quantos elementos de df também estão em df1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
df.loc[df['id'].isin(df1['id'])]
```

Answer (score 2):

Você pode utilizar a função `merge` para pegar a interseção e depois contar o elementos:

```
pd.merge(df, df1, on = "id", how="inner").count()
```

Answer (score 0):

Aproveitando a pergunta, esses códigos serviriam para dataframes totalmente diferentes tanto no número de linhas quanto no  número de  colunas?  E  se fôssemos comparar as linhas com textos entre os dois dataframes também serviria?